# Kafka: KafkaConsumer not able to pull all records

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api

I'm pretty new at Kafka.

For the purpose of stress testing my cluster, and building operational experience, I created two simple Java applications: one that repeatedly publishes messages to a topic (a sequence of integers) and another application that loads the entire topic (all records) and verifies that the sequence is complete. Expectation is that no messages get lost due to operations on the cluster (restart a node, replacing a node, topics partitions reconfigurations, etc).

The topic "sequence" has two partitions, and replication factor 3. The cluster is made of 3 virtual nodes (its for testing purposes, hence they are running on the same machine). The topic is configured to retain all messages (`retention.ms` set to `-1`)

I currently have two issues, that I have difficulties figuring out:

1. If I use `bin/kafka-console-consumer.sh --bootstrap-server kafka-test-server:9090,kafka-test-server:9091,kafka-test-server:9092 --topic sequence --from-beginning` I see ALL messages (even though not ordered, as expected) loaded on console. On the other hand, if I use the consumer application that I wrote, I see different results being loaded at each cycle: https://i.stack.imgur.com/tMK10.png - In the console output, the first line after the divisor is a call to `records.partitions()`, hence records are only sometimes pulled from both partitions. Why and why is the java app not behaving like `bin/kafka-console-consumer.sh`?
2. When the topic gets to big, the `bin/kafka-console-consumer.sh` is still able to show all messages, while the application is able to load only about 18'000 messages. I have tried playing around with 
   the various consumer-side configurations, with no progress. Again, the question is why is there a difference?

Thank you in advance for any hint!

Here are for ref. the two app discussed:

```java
package ch.demo.toys;

import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.util.Properties;
import java.util.concurrent.Future;
import org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.ConsumerConfig;
import org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.Callback;
import org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.KafkaProducer;
import org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.Producer;
import org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.ProducerRecord;
import org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.RecordMetadata;

public class SequenceProducer {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        Properties properties = new Properties();

        properties.load(new FileInputStream("toy.properties"));

        properties.put("key.serializer", "org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.IntegerSerializer");
        properties.put("value.serializer", "org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringSerializer");
        properties.put("acks", "1");
        properties.put("retries", "3");
        properties.put("compression.type", "snappy");
        properties.put(ConsumerConfig.AUTO_COMMIT_INTERVAL_MS_CONFIG, 1);

        for (Integer sequence_i = 0; true; sequence_i++) {
            try(Producer<Integer, String> producer = new KafkaProducer<>(properties)) {

                ProducerRecord<Integer, String> record = new ProducerRecord<>("sequence", sequence_i, "Sequence number: " + String.valueOf(sequence_i));

                Future<RecordMetadata> sendFuture = producer.send(record, (metadata, exception) -> {

                    System.out.println("Adding " + record.key() + " to partition " + metadata.partition());

                    if (exception != null) {
                        exception.printStackTrace();
                    }
                });
            }

            Thread.sleep(200);
        }
    }
}
```

```java
package ch.demo.toys;

import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.time.Duration;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Properties;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;
import org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.Consumer;
import org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.ConsumerConfig;
import org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.ConsumerRecords;
import org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.KafkaConsumer;
import org.apache.kafka.common.TopicPartition;

public class CarthusianConsumer {
    private static Properties getProperties() throws Exception {
        Properties properties = new Properties();
        properties.load(new FileInputStream("toy.properties"));

        properties.put(ConsumerConfig.KEY_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG,    org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.IntegerDeserializer.class);
        properties.put(ConsumerConfig.VALUE_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG,  org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringDeserializer.class);
        properties.put(ConsumerConfig.MAX_POLL_RECORDS_CONFIG,          Integer.MAX_VALUE);
        properties.put(ConsumerConfig.SESSION_TIMEOUT_MS_CONFIG,        60 * 1000);
        properties.put(ConsumerConfig.GROUP_ID_CONFIG,                  "carthusian-consumer");
        properties.put(ConsumerConfig.FETCH_MAX_WAIT_MS_CONFIG,         60 * 1000);
        properties.put(ConsumerConfig.ENABLE_AUTO_COMMIT_CONFIG,        false);
        properties.put(ConsumerConfig.AUTO_OFFSET_RESET_CONFIG,         "earliest");
        properties.put(ConsumerConfig.FETCH_MAX_BYTES_CONFIG,           1024 * 1024 * 1024);

        return properties;
    }

    private static boolean checkConsistency(List<Integer> sequence) {
        Collections.sort(sequence);

        Iterator<Integer> iterator = sequence.iterator();

        int control = 0;
        while(iterator.hasNext()) {
            int value = iterator.next();
            if (value != control) {
                System.out.println("");
                System.out.println("Gap found:");
                System.out.println("\tSequence: " + value);
                System.out.println("\tControl: " + control);
                return false;
            }

            control++;
        }

        System.out.print(".");
        return true;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

        // Step 1: create a base consumer object
        Consumer<Integer, String> consumer = new KafkaConsumer<>(getProperties());

        // Step 2: load topic configuration and build list of TopicPartitons
        List<TopicPartition> topicPartitions = consumer
                .partitionsFor("sequence")
                .stream()
                .parallel()
                .map(partitionInfo -> new TopicPartition(partitionInfo.topic(), partitionInfo.partition()))
                .collect(Collectors.toList());


        while (true) {
            List<Integer> sequence = new ArrayList<>();

            for (TopicPartition topicPartition : topicPartitions) {

                // Step 3. specify the topic-partition to "read" from
                // System.out.println("Partition specified: " + topicPartition);
                consumer.assign(Arrays.asList(topicPartition));

                // Step 4. set offset at the beginning
                consumer.seekToBeginning(Arrays.asList(topicPartition));

                // Step 5. get all records from topic-partition
                ConsumerRecords<Integer, String> records = consumer.poll(Duration.ofMillis(Long.MAX_VALUE));

                // System.out.println("\tCount: " + records.count());
                // System.out.println("\tPartitions: " + records.partitions());

                records.forEach(record -> { sequence.add(record.key()); });
            }


            System.out.println(sequence.size());

            checkConsistency(sequence);

            Thread.sleep(2500);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: the console consumer subscribes to the topic, while you are manually assigning partitions and starting offsets(seek). Is there any specific need for you to assign, instead of subscribing?

Comment: Good point. I forgot to mention that the subscription was the first approach, changed to direct assignment as a way to attempt solving my "issue"

Answer (score 1):

Thank you Mickael-Maison, here is my answer:

On producer: thanks you for the comment. I admit taking the example from the book and modifying it directly without performances considerations.

On consumer: as mentioned in the comments above, subscription was the first approach attempted which unfortunately yielded the same result described in my question: results from individual partitions, and only rarely from both partitions in the same call. I'd also love to understand the reasons for this apparently random behavior!

More on consumer: I rewind to the beginning of the topic at every cycle, because the purpose is to continuously verify that the sequence did not break (hence no messages lost). At every cycle I load all the messages and check them.

Because the single call based on topic subscription yielded an apparently random behavior (unsure when the full content of the topic is returned); I had to read off from each individual partition and join the lists of records manually before checking them - which is not what I wanted to do initially!

Are my approaches wrong?

Answer (score 0):

There are a few things you should change in your clients logic.

Producer:

You are creating a new producer for each record you're sending. This is terrible in terms of performance as each producer as to first bootstrap before sendign a record. Also as a single record is sent by each producer, no batching happens. Finally compression on a single record is also inexistant.

You should first create a Producer and use it to send all records, ie move the creation out of the loop, something like:

```java
try (Producer<Integer, String> producer = new KafkaProducer<>(properties)) {
    for (int sequence_i = 18310; true; sequence_i++) {

        ProducerRecord<Integer, String> record = new ProducerRecord<>("sequence", sequence_i, "Sequence number: " + String.valueOf(sequence_i));

        producer.send(record, (metadata, exception) -> {

            System.out.println("Adding " + record.key() + " to partition " + metadata.partition());

            if (exception != null) {
                exception.printStackTrace();
            }
        });
        Thread.sleep(200L);
    }
}
```

Consumer:

At every iteration of the for loop, you change the assignment and seek back to the beginning of the partition, so at best you will reconsume the same messages every time!

To begin, you should probably use the `subscribe()` API (like `kafka-console-consumer.sh`), so you don't have to fiddle with partitions. For example:

```java
try (Consumer<Integer, String> consumer = new KafkaConsumer<>(properties)) {

    consumer.subscribe(Collections.singletonList("topic"));

    while (true) {
        List<Integer> sequence = new ArrayList<>();

        ConsumerRecords<Integer, String> records = consumer.poll(Duration.ofSeconds(1L));
        records.forEach(record -> {
            sequence.add(record.key());
        });

        System.out.println(sequence.size());
        checkConsistency(sequence);

        Thread.sleep(2500L);
    }
}
```